# Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different component (`Home_Profile`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get this error while trying to navigate between screens with react native stack navigator. I think this was working in my previous project which had react 17.0.1 and react native 0.64.2, this project is react 17.0.2 and react native 0.66.4, helps would be appreciated.

**log**

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different component (`Home_Profile`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Home_Profile`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
```

error comes when I try to call navigation in an onPress prop on a Flatlist render item component.

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }}>
     <PostCard
        item={item}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home_Profile")}
     />
  </View>
)}
```

```
const PostCard = ({ item, onPress }) => {
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUserData() {
      const data = await getUserData(item.userid);
      setProfileimg(data.userimg);
      setName(data.name);
      setLocation(data.location);
    }
    fetchUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
            <Text
                style={{
                    color: "#231454",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: 15,
                    marginBottom: 3,
                }}
            >
                {name}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  )      
};

export default PostCard;
```

**Home_Profile**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";

const Home_Profile = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Home_Profile.js</Text>
      <Button title="back" onPress={navigation.navigate("Home")} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home_Profile;
```

Comment: Can you add your Home_Profile code ?

Comment: added Home_Profile

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, when you render the second screen, it is executing the onPress method of the button that goes back home, and that navigation causes the render method in that home screen to execute, which means you are trying to execute two renders at the same time, to fix that, just add an arrow function to the navigate home function as shown bellow:

```
onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate("Home")}}
```

Comment: you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add an arrow function before navigation.navigation('nameOFComponent')

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33805559)