# Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different component (`Context.consumer`)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, android-context

here my context file

```
import React from 'react';

import storage from '@helper/storage/user-storage';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

class AuthContextProvider extends React.Component{
    state = {
        user: null,
        nigth_mode: false, 
        token: null
    }

    login = async ({user, token}) => {
        await storage.storeUser(user)
        await storage.storeToken(token)

        this.setState({
            user: user,
            token: token
        })
    }

    logout = async () => {
        storage.removeAll().then(() => {
            this.setState({
                user: null,
                token: null
            })
        });
    }

    setUser = async (data) => {
        this.setState({
            user: data
        })
    }

    nigth_mode = async () => {
        this.setState({
            nigth_mode: !nigth_mode
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <AuthContext.Provider
                value={{
                    ...this.state,
                    login: this.login,
                    logout: this.logout,
                    setUser: this.setUser,
                    nigth_mode: this.nigth_mode,
                    token: this.state.token
                }}
            >
                { this.props.children }
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default AuthContextProvider
```

in my login file i have this render

```
render(){
        return(
            <AuthContext.Consumer>
                {context => {
                    console.log('token', context)
                    if(context.token){
                        // this.props.navigation.reset({
                        //  index: 0,
                        //  routes: [{ name: 'Home' }],
                        // });

                        this.props.navigation.navigate('View')
                    }else{
                        return(
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={['#232526', '#182848']}
                                style={styles.mainContainerLogin}>
                                <KeyboardAvoidingView
                                    style={styles.mainContainerLogin}
                                    behavior={'height'}
                                >
                                    {/* <View style={styles.loginLogo}>
                                        <Image
                                            source={require('../Images/ic-logo.jpg')}
                                            style={styles.logo}
                                        />
                                    </View> */}

                                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                                        <Ionicon
                                            name="md-person"
                                            size={20}
                                            color="rgb(110,182,245)"
                                            style={styles.inputIcon}
                                        />
                                        <TextInput
                                            placeholder={'Email'}
                                            placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'}
                                            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                            style={styles.loginInput}
                                            onChangeText={value => (this.userref = value)}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                                        <Ionicon
                                            name="md-lock-closed"
                                            size={20}
                                            color="rgb(110,182,245)"
                                            style={styles.inputIcon}
                                        />
                                        <TextInput
                                            placeholder="Password"
                                            placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'}
                                            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                            secureTextEntry={this.state.keyHide}
                                            style={styles.loginInput}
                                            onChangeText={value => (this.password = value)}
                                        />
                                        <TouchableOpacity
                                            style={styles.btnEye}
                                            onPress={this._showPassword.bind(this)}>
                                            <Ionicon
                                                name={
                                                    this.state.press == false ? 'md-eye' : 'md-eye-off'
                                                }
                                                size={20}
                                                color="rgb(110,182,245)"
                                            />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>

                                    {this._displayLoading()}
                                    {_errorTextLogin(this.state.error)}
                                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                                
                            </LinearGradient>
                        );
                    }
                }}
            </AuthContext.Consumer>
        );
```

so on clicking login button, the context.login is called, so it's set the state of token, so in my condition if my context.token exist i navigate to another page; if i console log on context.token, i got eh token when login is success,then the navigation is processed successfuly but i got a error popup on the new page

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`)  while rendering a different component (`Context.consumer`)
```

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562443/cannot-update-a-component-forwardrefbasenavigationcontainer-while-renderin) might help you